# Groups generated by elements - enumerating elements

Tags: group-theory, notation

From [Abstract Algebra in GAP](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf) by Alexander Hulpke, section 3.23 "Groups generated by elements":

> We have seen so far two ways of specifying subgroups: By listing
>   explicitly all elements, or by specifying a deﬁning property of the
>   elements. In some cases neither variant is satisfactory to specify
>   certain subgroups, and it is preferrable to specify a subgroup by
>   generating elements.
>
> **Deﬁnition**: Let $G$ be a group and $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n ∈ G$. The set
>
> $<a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n> = \\ \bigg \{ b_1^{\epsilon_1} \cdot b_2^{\epsilon_2} \ldots \ldots b_k^{\epsilon_k} | k \in N_0 = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}, b_i \in \{a_1, \ldots, a_n \}, \epsilon_i \in \{ 1, -1 \} \bigg \} $
>
> (with the convention that for $k = 0$ the product over the empty list
>   is $e$) is called the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a_1,...,a_n$.

My question is around the interpretation of the set notation above.

Let's say we have `<a,b>`. If I'd like to enumerate the set according to the definition above, is this the correct interpretation?

```
k = 0    ()

k = 1

    a
    a^-1
    b
    b^-1

k = 2    

    a    a
    a    a^-1
    a^-1 a
    a^-1 a^-1

    a    b
    a    b^-1
    a^-1 b
    a^-1 b^-1

    b    a
    b    a^-1
    b^-1 a
    b^-1 a^-1

    b    b
    b    b^-1
    b^-1 b
    b^-1 b^-1

k = 3

    ...
```

Comment: yes, that seems to be the correct interpretation, although its hard to tell only with $k=0,1,2$. How do you generate it for larger $k$?

Comment: @dharmatech: You have the right idea. For general $k$, we want all possible products of $k$ terms, where each term is either $a_i$ or $a_i^{-1}$, for some $i$. Hence in your example with two generators $a,b$, each of the $k$ factors must be one of $a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

*According to the definition*, yes, you are correct **so far**, but your enumeration of the set *as a set of group elements* is flawed in that it fails to take into account that cancellation happens each time an element and its inverse occur next to each other.